# Rails 3.0.5 NameError: uninitialized constant returns after attempting to generate controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, jquery-tokeninput

I just installed RVM on OSX (which was a pain), entered Rails Console in Terminal and wanted to generate a new Controller when I got the following:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Tags
    from (irb):9
    from /Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm a beginner to Rails and all this, so after the frustration of going through RVM I don't know what to do now. The model where I reference Tags is:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tag_tokens

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :body, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags, :through => :tagtokens
  has_many :responses, :tagtokens
  ...
end
```

FYI, I was attempting to implement jQuery TokenInput, following episode #258 of [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) closely.

**EDIT:** So I removed RVM and am now running Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.5. In Rails Console I tried `rails generate controller Tags` and got:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Tags
    from (irb):2
```

If there's any code I can paste that would be helpful please let me know.

Comment: did you named a model pluralize?

Comment: can you run this please: ls -l  app/*

Comment: Run exactly that in Terminal? I ran _ls -l app/*_ and got nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're running `rails generate controller Tags` **inside** the Rails Console. What you want to be doing is running it directly from the Terminal.

Comment: I'm really seeing the whole "it's about the little things" in a new light in learning to program. Thanks!

Comment: spent an hour on trying to resolve something similiar - glad I stumbled upon your answer. thanks!